# Nokogiri can't find external URL on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, nokogiri

I have a small Rails app that uses Nokogiri to parse an XML file on another site.  Locally, everything works fine.

However, when I deploy the app to Heroku, things break quickly - I keep getting the error `no such file or directory - <my url>`

Basically, the line in my code is

`doc = Nokogiri::XML(open("http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml"))`

The real URL is different, but I'm puzzling over why locally that runs without issue but Heroku can't deal with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`open-uri` is probably creating a `Tempfile` from your request (rather than a `String`). Heroku has some limitations on access to the filesystem, and probably isn't recognizing your tempfile. Try:

```
url_text = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml")
doc = Nokogiri::XML(url_text)
```

*Edit*: Nevermind it looks like Heroku works with `Tempfile` just fine. You probably just need to `require 'open-uri'` somewhere in your Rails initialization process (e.g., `application.rb`). If that still doesn't work, try the lines of code above.

Comment: Ah, thank you thank you thank you!  That `require 'open-uri'` statement was all that I needed.  I wish I had posted here two days ago!